# Left outer join null reference error in LINQ

Tags: vb.net, linq, join

I have the following code (or something like it):

```
Public Sub Load()
    Dim equipServices = {New Pair(20, 6), New Pair(21, 10), New Pair(22, 1)}
    Dim serviceTypes = {New Pair(1, 2), New Pair(6, 3), New Pair(9, 3)}
    Dim serviceIntervals = {New Pair(1, 0), New Pair(2, 0), New Pair(3, 0)}
    Dim equipmentList = _
        (From Service In equipServices _
         Group Join Type In serviceTypes On Service.second Equals Type.first Into Types = Group
         From Type In Types.DefaultIfEmpty()
         Group Join Interval In serviceIntervals On Type.second Equals Interval.first Into Intervals = Group
         From Interval In Intervals.DefaultIfEmpty()).ToList()
End Sub

Private Class Pair
    Public first As Integer
    Public second As Integer

    Public Sub New(first As Integer, second As Integer)
        Me.first = first
        Me.second = second
    End Sub
End Class
```

Essentially, I'm trying to do a left outer join of Types on Services, then a left outer join of Intervals on Types. This throws a System.NullReferenceException on Type.second when trying to join Type with Interval. I assume this is due to the fact that on the second Service pair, (21, 10), there is no matching Type. How can I arrange the query such that instead of this error, I just get a value of Nothing for Interval?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, you can check for "Nothing" during the join itself. I replaced this line:

```
Group Join Interval In serviceIntervals On Type.second Equals Interval.first Into Intervals = Group
```

with this line:

```
Group Join Interval In serviceIntervals On If(IsNothing(Type), Nothing, Type.second) Equals Interval.first Into Intervals = Group
```

and it worked out fine.